# Generate unique id - doctrine - symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to generate a unique ticket ID for my tickets. But how to let doctrine generate a unique id?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

little more explain:

- id must be 6 charters like: 678915
- id must be unique

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As of [version 2.3](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/doctrine/doctrine2.git/class-Doctrine.ORM.Id.UuidGenerator.html), you can just add the following annotations to your property:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
 */
protected $id;
```

Answer (score 41):

Use custom GeneratedValue strategy:

**1.** In your Entity class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="AppBundle\Doctrine\RandomIdGenerator")
 */
protected $id;
```

**2.** Then create file `AppBundle/Doctrine/RandomIdGenerator.php` with content

```
namespace AppBundle\Doctrine;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;

class RandomIdGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{
    public function generate(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        $entity_name = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity))->getName();

        // Id must be 6 digits length, so range is 100000 - 999999
        $min_value = 100000;
        $max_value = 999999;

        $max_attempts = $min_value - $max_value;
        $attempt = 0;

        while (true) {
            $id = mt_rand($min_value, $max_value);
            $item = $em->find($entity_name, $id);

            // Look in scheduled entity insertions (persisted queue list), too
            if (!$item) {
                $persisted = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions();
                $ids = array_map(function ($o) { return $o->getId(); }, $persisted);
                $item = array_search($id, $ids);
            }

            if (!$item) {
                return $id;
            }

            // Should we stop?
            $attempt++;
            if ($attempt > $max_attempts) {
                throw new \Exception('RandomIdGenerator worked hardly, but failed to generate unique ID :(');
            }  
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How to deal with collisions? in a web application, before the generated id is flushed in the db, it is possible that another request has generated and flushed the very same id. Is there a more robust solution?

Comment: @VincentPazeller, I think there is no way to handle this type of collision in absolute. You can only decrease probablity of collision. For example, extending ID range or adding something like 2 digits milliseconds of current timestamp in the beginning of ID (so collision probablity equals probablity of generation two same ID in your range by requests came in one millisecond in condition that time between generation ID and flushing it is less than 99 milliseconds) or adding some request-specified marker. Any other ideas?

Comment: Instead of raising an exception, why don't you loop until you get a non existing ID?

Comment: @Nicolas, there is a logical bug in this code. Exception never be raised because cycle is infinite ;) You are free to write your own random ID generator, it's just an example, not best of the world. For example, to make this cycle not infinite you can add increment counter and break the loop when it reach maximum value. If "Id must be 6 charters like: 678915" we cannot loop more than 999999 times.

Comment: I corrected code example, so it consider maximum attempts to generate unique ID.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PrePersist annotation, like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function preSave() {
    $this->id = uniqid();
}
```

As the annotation name suggest, it will be run before object persistence into database.

For unique id, I simply use a native php uniqid() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php which will return 13 characters. To get only 6 characters, refer to this [PHP Ticket ID Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677836/php-ticket-id-generation)

In the $id property, I think you also need to remove this line to prevent auto generated value of it:

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
```

Comment: This seems to work outside of the `@Id` annotation as the `@Id` is generated after the `PrePersist` event, so I don't think it can be substituted to the original `@Id`.

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine will treat this field as your primary key (because of the `@Id` annotation), so this field is already unique. If you have the `@GeneratedValue` annotation on `AUTO` strategy Doctrine will figure out which strategy to use dependend on the db platform. It will default to `IDENTITY` on MySql and the field will be a `auto_increment` then.

You can write the id annotation without the brackets as follows.

- ORM\Id

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell that I want to have the id like: 986016 (6numbers) and the id must be unique.

Comment: How about `ALTER TABLE mytable SET AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000`, Or take care about the ID generation in your application code. Why do you want 6 numbers? You can also zero fill to 6 chars (`str_pad`) when you are presenting the number and just use a simple auto_increment for your id in the database.

Comment: no sorry, I want unique and diffrent numbers, so not 100001, 100002, 100003.

Comment: Create a seperate table containing all possible ticket ID's ie 100000-999999 and a flag to indicate if it is used or not. Before persisting your ticket select a random ticket id from the table and set `used` to true. Remove the `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm seconding the UUID approach suggested by Jonhathan, you could prefer a shorter, more readable, identifier. In this case you can use [ShortId Doctrine bundle](https://github.com/PUGX/shortid-doctrine-bundle).

Comment: Is not compatible with php 5.* but seems a great solution