# PHP and Doctrine: how to create unique IDs

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'd like to create unique IDs, something like `dujUSJue9389sjgjik`.

I've used the Doctrine's `UUID` strategy to create them, but the result is something like `d9c363ae-a1b7-11e6-a66d-9e9923e30d94`: I don't like the use of dashes and also I'd like to have shorter IDs.

They have to identify some entities to build an URL like `http://example.com/entity/hduicw43tv43bic`.

Using PHP's `uniqid()` doesn't guarantee the uniqueness of the generated value. I think a conflict is very rare, but, anyway, not excluded at all, so I'm not considering it "secure" (a conflict may cause an exception and the rows creation may cause a lot of headache to fix).

So, using Doctrine and Symfony, I'm looking for a way to generate a value like `ajybUYBD74883bj8d74NJ` and check for its uniqueness. If it is already present, a new value has to be generated. Once the entity has a unique value, it can be persisted. The generation should happen when the entity is created.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: There's no real unique value generation algorithm that guarantees uniqueness, including UUID/GUID.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. For this I'm looking for a procedure to check the uniqueness and on fail (the generated ID already exists) regenerate it. This should be done in Doctrine entity itself.

Comment: This should be done in entity itself. It's not entity's job to check other entities (inclufing calling repository). It should be ID generator's job. You can try to create a custom ID generator, but I can't find documentation about it. Anyway here's an example in psylosss's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039665/generate-unique-id-doctrine-symfony2

Comment: UUID is just a number. You can display it as hexadecimal text with inserted hyphen characters, but it's still a 128-bit value. You can represent it as you want (e.g: base64-encoded)

Comment: @Federkun, yes, for sure, but I don't want it be too much long... Maybe UUID has a technical meaning, but I'm intending it simply as a unique value to identify an entity, without constraints on length, format or anything else. Its unique property, for the purpose of this question, is its uniqueness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, mixing the [answer by @Matteo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40402193/1399706) and the [answer by psyloss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401218/1399706) suggested by @Jakub Matczak I came up with this:

```
class Company
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="AppBundle\Doctrine\IdGenerator")
     */
     private $id;

     ...
```

and then

```
namespace AppBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
class IdGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        $uuid = Uuid::uuid4()->getHex();

        if (null !== $em->getRepository(get_class($entity))->findOneBy(['id' => $uuid])) {
            $uuid = $this->generate($em, $entity);
        }

        return $uuid;
    }
}
```

This generator also checks for an existing entity with the same name, regenerating the UUID if required and guaranteeing the uniqueness.

The generated value is exactly what I want: `7b165049eb224f548021f68caefc57f6`.

Answer (score 2):

If Doctrine's UUID strategy is good you can simply transform that:

```
$in = 'd9c363ae-a1b7-11e6-a66d-9e9923e30d94';
$out = base_convert(strtr($in,'-',''),16,36);
print_r($out);
```

short, no dash, reverseable

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the [ramsey-uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) library, ad Use As Follow:

```
$uuid = \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4();
echo $uuid->getHex();
```

Alternately, if you already have a UUID, you may do this:

```
$uuid = \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::fromString('f6a1fd62-1445-42fc-9e7b-d8c6e9da33a1');
echo $uuid->getHex();
```

More info [in this article](https://benramsey.com/projects/ramsey-uuid/)

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Ramsey uuid lib is auch good start point. There is also an library from anthony https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib.

But take care about uuid, they can corrupt your data! Also you can't check with a select if the id is already in the DB. If two users will create 2 records at the same time they can get the same id.