# Cannot assign <IdClass> to property of type <EntityClass>

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have the following entity graph:

```php
#[ORM\Entity]
class Professional
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'professional_id')]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'NONE')]
    private ProfessionalId $id;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: ProfessionalCatchmentArea::class, mappedBy: 'professional', cascade: ['all'])]
    private ?ProfessionalCatchmentArea $catchmentArea = null;
}
```

```php
#[ORM\Entity]
class ProfessionalCatchmentArea
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: Professional::class, inversedBy: 'catchmentArea')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private Professional $professional;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: ProfessionalCatchmentAreaZone::class, mappedBy: 'catchmentArea', orphanRemoval: true, cascade: ['all'])]
    private Collection $zones;
}
```

```php
#[ORM\Entity]
class ProfessionalCatchmentAreaZone
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid')]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'NONE')]
    private Uuid $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: ProfessionalCatchmentArea::class, inversedBy: 'zones')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'professional_id', referencedColumnName: 'professional_id', nullable: false)]
    private ProfessionalCatchmentArea $catchmentArea;
}
```

Note: `ProfessionalId` is a custom ID class containing a UUID.

As you can see, `Professional` has a one-to-one relationship with `ProfessionalCatchmentArea`, which in turn has a one-to-many relationship with `ProfessionalCatchmentAreaZone`.

Due to the one-to-one, `ProfessionalCatchmentArea` shares its primary key with `Professional`.

Therefore, the `JoinColumn` for the many-to-one relationship from `ProfessionalCatchmentAreaZone` to `ProfessionalCatchmentArea` is based on the `professional_id` column.

For some reason, even though Doctrine does not complain with this mapping (`bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` is OK), and even though traversal from `Professional` to `$catchmentArea` to `$zones` works fine, attempting to load the `ProfessionalCatchmentAreaZone` entities directly from the `EntityRepository` fails:

```php
$entityManager->getRepository(ProfessionalCatchmentAreaZone::class)->findAll();
```

> Cannot assign `App\Entity\ProfessionalId` to property `App\Entity\ProfessionalCatchmentArea::$professional` of type `App\Entity\Professional`

**Any idea why?**

Is this mapping *one-to-one => one-to-many*, while sharing the primary key in the one-to-one relationship, not supported? **Is this a Doctrine bug?**

Comment: Shouldn't you declare the Id of `ProfessionalCatchmentArea` as `ProfessionalId $id`, exactly like you did for the `Professional` entity?

Comment: @Olivier Before checking if that would work for me, one question: is there a way to enforce a foreign key on `ProfessionalCatchmentArea.professionalId` if it's declared as a `ProfessionalId` and not as a `OneToOne` to `Professional`? Does Doctrine allow declaring a foreign key if it's not an association?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Doctrine so I can't answer those questions.

Comment: Show the `ProfessionalId` type  source.

Comment: In order to replicate your issue it would be helpful to get info about: PHP version, Packages version (or composer.lock), Database vendor and version, Example code to populate database with some dummy data.

Comment: I spent some time on this, even built tables based on your example. One thing I was not able to reproduce were those `uuid` and `professional_id` types of columns. The rest, with int column types does work OK. So I would not look into relation configuration any more.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a few ideas:

1. Based on the information provided, I'm inclined to believe this is an issue with the object inheritance and the mapped type for the data type of `Professional->$id`.

   Given that *ProfessionalId* extends the *UUID*, the only valid class datatype for *ProfessionalId* is the class *ProfessionalId*.

   If the data type was UUID then the values that are compatible with *UUID* would be an instance of *UUID* or *ProfessionalId* (because it INHERITS *UUID*).
2. Check that the Datatype is registered for that name:

   ```php
   <?php

   // In your bootstrap file

   \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType('professional_id', ProfessionalId::class);

   ?>
   ```
3. Ensure that the *ProfessionalId* type inherits the annotations from the *UUID* type as seen here:

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/40442063/5779200